# group action of $\mathbb{F}_q$ on a $\mathbb{F}_p$-vector space.

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory, vector-spaces, group-actions

Question: Let $p, q$ be distinct prime numbers. Let $V$ be a $\mathbb{F}_p$-vector space.  Does there exists a non-trivial $\mathbb{F}_p$-linear action of $\mathbb{F}_q$ on $V$?

My guess in that there doesn't exists a non-trivial action and here is a proof which I have thought of (but at one point I am not so sure):

Suppose the action is non-trivial then for $1 \in \mathbb{F}_q$ there exists a $v \in V$ such that $1\cdot v = w$, where $w \neq v$. Now consider the action $1\cdot (pv) = p(1\cdot v)= p\cdot v$ (since the action is $\mathbb{F}_p$-linear). This implies $p\cdot v = 0$, which is a contradiction because action of $p \in \mathbb{F}_q$ is a vector space isomorphism and by assumption $v \neq 0$.

Is this reasoning correct ?

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: The beginning looks weird: why would there be $\;v\in V\;$ s.t. $\;1\cdot v=w\;$ and $\;v\neq w\;$ , as if it were a requirement?

Comment: @DonAntonio As $\mathbb{F}_q$ is cyclic group with generator $1$, so the action of any element of $\mathbb{F}_q$ is determined by the action $1$. So if $1 \in \mathbb{F}_q$ acts trivially on V, then whole of $\mathbb{F}_q$ will act trivially. So WLOG we can assume that the action of $1$ is not trivial.

Comment: The place where I am not confident is when I take $p \in \mathbb{F}_p$ outside because of $\mathbb{F}_p$-linearity and then in the third equality I am thinking of $p$ as an element of $\mathbb{F}_q$. Is that allowed ?

Comment: Ok, I think we're mixing stuff here: if you refer to $\;\Bbb F_q\;$ as "a cyclic group with generator $\;1\;$", then you are in fact referring to the multiplicative group $\;\Bbb F_q^*=\Bbb F_q\setminus\{0\}\;$ , which is **not** the whole field, and thus the group's unit **must** act on the given set trivially. This is a requirement of group actions, not an option...but I thought you meant *the whole group* $\;\Bbb F_q\;$ , so which one is it?

Comment: And $\;p\;$ as an element of $\;\Bbb F_p\;$ is **exactly the same as** zero...

Comment: If you are looking for an action of the *additive* group of $\Bbb{F}_q$, then the axioms of action dictate the rule
$$(a+b)\cdot x= a\cdot (b\cdot x)$$ for all $a,b\in\Bbb{F}_q$, $x\in V$. It does **not** follow that $p\cdot x =px=0$. $\Bbb{F}_p$-linearity of action only means that
$$a\cdot (\alpha x+\beta y)=\alpha (a\cdot x)+\beta (a\cdot y)$$ for all $a\in\Bbb{F}_q$, $x,y\in V$ and $\alpha,\beta\in\Bbb{F}_p$.

Comment: For example, if $p>2$, $q=2$, then the additive group $\Bbb{F}_2$ acts on any vector space $V$ over $\Bbb{F}_p$ by the rules:
$$0\cdot x=x, \qquad 1\cdot x=-x.$$

Comment: @DonAntonio I am looking at $\mathbb{F}_q$ as an additive group. And $\mathbb{F}_p$ as a field. Also, $1$ does generate the additive group $\mathbb{F}_q$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thanks a lot for that counter example. So if I put a further restrictions that both $p$ and $q$ are distinct odd primes, then do you think one can still come up with a counter example ?

Comment: @ultron My answer gives a general recipe. In the general case we need $\dim V$ to be high enough to find a non-trivial action. When $q\mid p-1$ we get counterexamples in every dimension. For example when $q=3$, $p=7$ we have $2^3\equiv1\pmod 7$. This means that $\Bbb{F}_3$ acts non-trivially on any space $V$ over $\Bbb{F}_7$ by the rules
$$0\cdot x=x,\quad 1\cdot x= 2x,\quad 2\cdot x=4x.$$

Comment: There is a nontrivial $\Bbb F_p$-linear action of $\Bbb Z_q$ (where $q$ is prime) on $\Bbb F_p^n$ if and only if $q$ divides the order of $GL_n\Bbb F_p$, which is $(p^n-1)\cdots(p^n-p^{n-1})$. This is equivalent to ${\rm ord}_qp\le n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A crucial mistake in your argument is the claim that
$p\cdot v= 0$, where $p$ in the left would be an element of the field $\Bbb{F}_q$. The step
$$
1\cdot (pv)=p(1\cdot v)
$$
does follow from the linearity (though $pv=0$ as well as $p(1\cdot v)=0$, so this is not very interesting). But $p(1\cdot v)$ is unrelated to $p\cdot v$.

To see the error consider the case $p=2$. We have for all $v\in V$
$$
2\cdot v=(1+1)\cdot v=1\cdot(1\cdot v),
$$
and there is no way to combine the $1$s on the right hand side.
May be the mistake is that you falsely expected the group operation of $\Bbb{F}_q$, the addition, to magically correspond to the addition in $V$?
In fact, in addition to the rule $0\cdot x=x$ (the neutral element acts trivially) all that the action prescribes is
$$
(a+b)\cdot v= a\cdot (b\cdot v)
$$
for all $a,b\in\Bbb{F}_q$ and all $v\in V$. The requirement that the action should be $\Bbb{F}_p$-linear means that
$$
a\cdot(\alpha v+\beta w)=\alpha(a\cdot v)+\beta (a\cdot w)
$$
for all $a\in\Bbb{F}_q$, $\alpha,\beta\in\Bbb{F}_p$ and $v,w\in V$.

---

There exist non-trivial linear actions of the additive group $\Bbb{F}_q$ on the vector space $V=\Bbb{F}_p^n$ if the dimension $n$ is large enough. We really only want a cyclic group of order $q$ to act on $V$ by $\Bbb{F}_p$-linear transformations.

Let $d$ be the smallest positive integer such that $q\mid p^d-1$. By Little Fermat
$p^{q-1}\equiv1\pmod q$, so $d$ will be a factor of $q-1$. I claim that $n\ge d$ is all we need.

Consider the extension field $K=\Bbb{F}_{p^d}$. Its multiplicative group is cyclic of order $p^d-1$ so there exists an element $\mu\in K^*$ such that $\mu\neq1$ and $\mu^q=1$.
We can define an $\Bbb{F}_p$-linear action of $\Bbb{F}_q$ on $K$ by declaring that for
all $a\in\{0,1,2,\ldots,q-1\}$ we have
$$\overline{a}\cdot x=\mu^a x.$$
Because $\mu^q=1$, this is well-defined. Because $\mu^{a+b}=\mu^a\mu^b$ it defines an action of $(\Bbb{F}_q,+)$. Because multiplication by any element of $K$ obviously yields an $\Bbb{F}_p$-linear transformation $K\to K$, the action is $\Bbb{F}_p$-linear.

If $n\ge d$, we can choose $V=K\oplus \Bbb{F}_p^{n-d}$, and let $\Bbb{F}_q$ act on $K$ as above, and trivially on $\Bbb{F}_p^{n-d}$.

It is not difficult to show that the condition $n\ge d$ is also necessary for the space $\Bbb{F}_p^n$ to have a linear transformation of order $q$.